# Python was not found when executing a .py file on Git Bash MINGW64

Tags: python, git-bash, mingw-w64

I want to run a python file in the Git bash but it is not executing without adding py before the file name. Python is installed but when I use the shortcut to execute the python file, an error is shown as below-

```
user@WinPC MINGW64 /d/git_basic/scripts (main)                     
$ python                                               
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32              
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                        
>>> quit()                                             
                                                       
user@WinPC MINGW64 /d/git_basic/scripts (main)                     
$ ./all_checks.py                                      
Python was not found; run without arguments to install 
from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Please guide me. Thanks

### Edit 1

What I want is to run the python file in the terminal without using python or py in the command (py file.py or python file.py). I want to run it like this ./file.py

This is the all_checks.py code-

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

def check_reboot():
    # returns true if pc has a pending reboot
    return os.path.exists("/run/reboot-required")

def main():
    if check_reboot():
        print("pending reboot.")
        sys.exit(1)
    print("No pending reboot.")
    sys.exit(0)

main()
```

### Edit 2

I was able to run the file with ./ by just changing the python3 to python in the shebang line.

Comment: What is the first line of your python file? Does it look like `#!python` or similar?

Comment: with your current setup, `python ./all_checks.py` may work for you

Answer (score 0):

I was not clear on exactly what you wanted but I have 2 options here.
Just running the file and making the file an executable.

If you just want to run it then use the terminal command, `python file-name` or `python3 file-name` if you have any python 2 installations.

You do not run a python file with this command: `./file-name`

However, if you want to make it an executable file keep on reading.

If you are trying to make an executable, pyinstaller will do the job for you. If you have pip, then run the command `pip install pyinstaller`. Then, once you have pyinstaller installed, open terminal or command prompt and locate the directory of the python file using cd. Then once you are in the directory in terminal/command prompt run the command `pyinstaller --onefile file-name` include `-w` after --onefile if you do not want the command prompt/terminal/command-line to open up when run.

(Pyinstaller works for all operating systems)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the file with ./ by just changing the python3 to python in the shebang line.

[Python 3 Docs - Shebang lines](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).